# Is there any proof that Euclid's fifth postulate cannot be proven?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, math-history, noneuclidean-geometry

I've read many times that a plethora of people have tried to prove Euclid's parallel postulate but to no avail. However, I do not know of any proof of how it cannot be proven. Is it because modifying it leads to different and consistent geometries and you can just state such a thing? How do you know your geometry is consistent?

Comment: You can construct examples of geometries where the other axioms are satisfied but the parallel postulate is not. This shows that the parallel postulate does not follow from the other axioms.

Comment: Yes; it's because there are other, consistent geometries. The various models of Poincaré geometry (or spherical geometry) serve as guidelines, establishing consistency in much the same way that the Euclidean plane model establishes consistency of the standard Euclidean geometry.

Comment: It can be proved that hyperbolic geometry, for example, is consistent if and only if Euclidean geometry is consistent, if and only if the arithmetic of the real number system is consistent.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "The independence of the parallel postulate from Euclid's other axioms was finally demonstrated by Eugenio Beltrami in 1868." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate#Converse_of_Euclid's_parallel_postulate

Comment: A postulate can't be proved for its own definition; you can prove a theorem instead.